# Why are Gyrich and Blitzschlag working with Pym?

Tags: marvel, avengers, avengers-initiative

From reading Avengers: The Initiative, Gyrich and Blitzschlag don't seem such nice people. Pym even says so himself at one point until Blitzschlag tells him that Pym is his 'hero' for creating such evil creations as Ultron and clone!Thor (bonus points to name the trope in the comments).

But it does raise the question, when and why did these two supposed villains join the 'heroes' side?

Answer (score 1):

Gyrich is often depicted as an antagonist but he isn't a villain, at least not during Initiative. Gyrich started as the government liaison to the Avengers. Gyrich made many salient points regarding the Avenger's caviler attitude toward security and international law.(Avengers Vol.1 168,172,186) Gyrich was the government liaison at Camp Hammond. Gyrich abused his power to create the Shadow Initiative but he wasn't overtly villainous. Gyrich was at Camp Hammond because it was his job.(Avengers the Iniative #2)

Baron Von Blitzschlag was objectively a vilian. Blitzschlag working for the government in no doubt a reference to the real world "Operation Paperclip." where more than 1600 German scientists, including Nazis, were recruited and brought to the United States to work in the fields of aeronautics, medicine, etc.(Avengers the Inititive #4)

With all of that out of the way...Gyrich is on the side of heroes because it is his job and Blitzschlag is there because the government provides for him to continue his experiments.(Avengers the Initiative #7,8,10,15)

Edit: added citations.

Comment: An interesting answer, however it is lacking some canonical evidence. Are there any sources you can find for your answer to provide evidence for you thoughts to strengthen your answer?

Comment: Added citations.